# Materialize inputs not triggering onChange in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I have a Materialize input like so:

```
<input type="date" className="datepicker" onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
```

It is being correctly initialised by Materialize, but not firing onChange when the value of the datepicker changes. What am I doing wrong here? This problem seems to extend to all Materialize inputs.

Comment: did u try binding this to the function if you are using ES6, ex: onChange={this.props.handleChange.bind(this)};

Comment: @Vikramaditya Unfortunately I'm not using ES6, will try to find a commonjs way though. Thanks.

Comment: @Vikramaditya I get this error `React component methods may only be bound to the component instance`...

Comment: I am having the same issue. onChange is simply not triggering using Materialize for this datepicker.  It works fine for the normal fields though, what am I missing?

Comment: Dear @j_d, please test the `onChange` with the following function, `onChange={function(e) { console.log(e.target.value)}}`, if it show the chosen date on the console so you should put the `handleChange` function inside your question. maybe the issue is from `handleChange`

Comment: Dear @j_d, do you test my opinion? I just wanna help you.

Comment: @j_d can you send ```handleChange``` function? Maybe your function not binded on constructor like ```this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)```? Or if you use arrow function: ```const handleChange = (value) => {}```. According your error somewhere you don't binded your function.

Comment: You should provide the code to show how the `handleChange` implemented and passed to your component. IMHO, your problem is irrelevant to `Material` as well.

Answer (score 1):

On **componentDidUpdate()** using a prop **id**

```
var elem = document.getElementById('date');
        M.Datepicker.init(elem,{
            onClose:()=>{
                this.state.date = elem.value;                    
                this.setState(this.state)
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this solves the caveat if you put it in your componentDidMount component.
If the select is to be re-rendered on state change, this should as well be put in componentDidUpdate

```
// find the select element by its ref
const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.ref_to_my_select);
// initialize the select
$('select').material_select();
// register a method to fireup whenever the select changes
$(el).on('change', this.handleInputChange)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the datepicker in materialize they provide an [onSelect](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html#date-picker) option when initialising the component:

```
var instances = M.Datepicker.init(
      elems,
      {
        onSelect:function(){
          date = instances[0].date;
          console.log(date);
        }
      }
    );
```

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/dyopgpa

Every time you pick a date, onSelect fires, in this case console.logging the chosen date.

When you close the datepicker (which is actually a modal), that's when the onChange fires, in this case logging 'onChange triggered' to the console.

Answer (score 0):

that's my solution. I use useRef hook, to identify datepicker input and when onClose is fired, we can capture the object and data value, through ref var.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import M from "materialize-css";

export default function App() {

  const fromref = useRef(null); //create reference

  const [date, setDate] = useState({ fromdate: "" });

  const { fromdate } = date;

  useEffect(() => {
    let elem = document.querySelectorAll(".datepicker");
    M.Datepicker.init(elem, {
      firstDay: true,
      format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
      onClose: function() { // when onclose datepicker, we can get the value and data through the ref
        console.log(fromref.current.name, fromref.current.value);
        setDate({ [fromref.current.name]: fromref.current.value });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input
            name="fromdate"
            type="text"
            class="datepicker"
            placeholder="from date"
            ref={fromref} //set reference to the input
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the **value** or other **attributes** you can access them from **instaces** variable when initialized and then check *before submitting your form*.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.timepicker');
var instances = M.Timepicker.init(elems);
```

Then in order to get your value before submitting your form can do as follow:

```
var date = instances[0].el.value;
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two things which might be stopping the execution of expected behaviour.

---

1. If the code which you have displayed question section is from
   rendered html tree, then onchnage assigment needs to be called while
   assignment itself.

> ```
> <input type="date" className="datepicker" onChange=this.props.handleChange(event)/>
> ```

- Note: Previously browser events use to expects event callback
  handlers in string format as a value.

---

- In MaterializeCss documentation there is no mentioning of onChange event, this means there cannot be direct way to get it.
- https://materializecss.com/pickers.html

---

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're using materialize directly in your post but if it is possible, you could try using [`react-materialize`](http://react-materialize.github.io/react-materialize/?path=/story/react-materialize--welcome) as it wraps all the materialize components such that it's easier to use with React. Using `react-materialize` would probably be the cleanest way to handle state and event changes as they provide a convenience wrapper around each materialize component.

When using the date picker from `react-materialize`, you'll need to pass the `handleChange` method into the options prop like so:

```
<DatePicker
  options={{
    ...,
    onSelect: this.props.handleChange
  }}
 />
```

In the case of using the materialize date picker independently, if you could provide more details on how you're initializing the date picker input, I could provide a more relevant answer. But I'll give it a shot in the dark.

From the [materialize docs](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html) it looks like you'll also have to pass back some options when you initialize it to handle a callback function when a date is selected.

I've added a JSFiddle that has a working example as well as a code snippet below, notice that when you select a date, 'hello world' is logged in the console, and the date is the first argument passed into the callback.

```
class Datepicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    console.log('hello world', date);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
      var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, {
        onSelect: this.handleChange
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <input type="text" className="datepicker" />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Live Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xta0oL9w/)

So to answer your question of how to handle events and setting the state, you just need to pass your `handleChange` method into the provided options configs depending on how you're using materialize date picker. In regards to integrating with a form, you could use the other callback hooks like onClose to do form validation.